# OOAD clarification on multiplicity or cardinality

Tags: uml, class-diagram, ooad, multiplicity

I am confused about the cardinality/ multiplicity when designing class diagrams.
My main confusion is when to represent 1---* relationship. For ex in case of passenger and seat classes, passenger will be allotted to one seat, where as the seat can be allotted to one passenger at A POINT IN TIME but over a period of its existence it can be allotted to many passengers.

**So should the seat--->passenger be 1-1 or 1-*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's summarize:

- At one precise moment in time:

  - each `Passenger` will be allocated to exactly one `Seat` (1).  Open question: does the `Passenger` exists already before the allocation  (i.e. 1 or 0..1) ?
  - each `Seat` can have one allocated `Passenger` but it may remain empty (so 0..1)
- Over their lifetime:

  - each `Passenger` can have been allocated to many seats (one per flight)
  - each `Seat` can have had many `Passenger` allocated.

Conclusions:  the relation between `Seat` and `Passenger` is `*-*` (many to many)

Comment: Thanks CHristopher. When do we need to consider is it over a period of time or at a time? Is it a question to the customer like I need to ask them are you looking for over a period of time or at a point in time? or should it always be for every design u consider over a period of time?

Comment: It depends on your customer's needs.  So you have to ask him/her questions that help you to clarify. Don't hestitate to ask questions under different angles.  For example: does he/she want to find back the history of the seat allocation ? does he/she expect that seats can be allocated in advance (a Passenger could then reserve seats for several travels) ?  are there legal requirements (finding back the seats in case of law enforcement investigation) ? and so on... Real life is full of many to many relationships

Answer (score -1):

It all depends **what** you model.

- If we're modelling a booking per trip it will be a Seat 1 --- 0..1
  Passenger.
- If we're modelling a booking per trip and have just a number of
  seats per each class (but a particular seat isn't assigned) it can
  be SeatClass 1 --- 0..SeatClass.availableSeats Passenger.
- If we're modelling a system to analyse passenger behaviour (e.g.
  to offer best seat for a particular passenger) it will be a
  Passenger 1 <>--- * Seat.
- If we're modelling a system to analyse the seat utilisation it can
  be Seat 1 <>--- * Passenger.

etc.

I can imagine lots of other possibilities.

The idea is you model a particular system and you need to represent particular business need. Multiplicity will depend on that. As a rule of thumb you are interested in a situation in a point of time (note that in my two last examples you're handling a history of seats assignments at a point of time).

So my conclusion is: there is no simple answer.